# Can Redis re-read TLS key when key is updated w/o restarted?

Tags: redis

Redis can support TLS now. But when TLS key is updated, can redis re-read it w/o restarting it? that is to say, when key file is updated, redis can automatically refresh all connection.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we use redis a lot in this way. We use it as a cache as well for large calls.

Comment: Thanks you a lot for your comments, how do you implement it?